# Finding and switching to the right frame with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to write a WebDriver test for the following site for learning purposes: http://www.mate1.com

On clicking the login link, I get a form to fill in my email id and password. As far as I understand, the form is shown in an iframe.

To enter the credentials, I tried to identify the number of iframes for that particular page (and found it as 7) and tried switching in to each iframe and search for the email field by XPath and the ID. However, I wasn't successful to find it. So how can this be done?

This is my code:

```
driver.get("http:www.mate1.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='header-container']/div/a")).click();
List <WebElement> frames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
System.out.println("Totalframes -> "+ frames.size());
driver.switchTo().frame(0);                
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='email']")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx@rocketmail.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a good situation to use `switchTo().frame(WebElement)`:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(findElement(By.cssSelector(".iframe-container>iframe")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The login and password fields are not in an iframe, you can directly use the following code -

driver.findelement(By.id("email").sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx@rocketmail.com");

Try not to switch to any iframe and execute the above line, this will work.

Comment: ., No they are in an iframe and it wasn't possible for me to identify them by the Xpath or the ID